# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension when plotting dataframe column of integers

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a a dataframe with year/month column and a `int` column. 
It looks like this:

```
         Date     count
0  2018-01-01  19730570
1  2018-02-01  19301103
2  2018-03-01  21962470
3  2018-04-01  21034792
4  2018-05-01  21556113
5  2018-06-01  21118266
6  2018-07-01  21584891
7  2018-08-01  22101502
8  2018-09-01  22123605
9  2018-10-01  23266816
10 2018-11-01  22861081
```

I am trying to graph this using matplot, but i keep getting an error that my x and y are different dimensions, when clearly they are not.

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (11,) and (1,)
```

I already converted my date column to datetime, but still am unsure why I am getting this error.

Here is what I am trying to execute:

```
plt.plot(monthly_trips_fhv.Date, monthly_trips_fhv.count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [`pandas.DataFrame.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) is a dataframe method.

  - Your column name is mirroring that method name, so you need to use `monthly_trips_fhv['count']`

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# sample data
data = {'Date': ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01'],
        'count': [19730570, 19301103, 21962470, 21034792, 21556113, 21118266, 21584891, 22101502, 22123605, 23266816, 22861081]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# make sure the Date column is the correct Dtype
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.date

# plot with implicit "pyplot" interface
plt.plot('Date', 'count', data=df)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.show()

# or plot with the explicit "Axes" interface
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot('Date', 'count', data=df)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=90)
```

Plot the dataframe directly. Specify the column to use for `x`, and the other column will automatically be used as `y`.

```py
# or plot with pandas.DataFrame.plot (matplotlib is the backend)
ax = df.plot(x='Date', rot=90, legend=False)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Pandas's plot function:

```
df.plot(x='Date', y='count')
```

Output:

[image]